# Concatenate two strings into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have code I created with the help of the internet.

It loops through a list to find a specific string. Then it takes column B cell and pastes it onto another workbook.

But I have two different strings in the list. each time my code overwrites the first string.

I want to concatenate the two but with a comma between. e.g. [16, 5]

```
DATA

[C]_GA-M126_ST16_1.5_1      16
[C]_GA-M126_ST16_1.5_2      16
[C]_GA-M126_ST16_1.5_3      16
[C]_GA-M126_ST16_1.5_4      16
[C]_GA-M126_ST16_1.5_159    5
[C]_GA-M126_ST16_1.5_160    5
[C]_GA-M126_ST16_1.5_161    5
[C]_GA-M126_ST16_1.5_162    5
```

```vb
Sub POP_LT_UNC()

    Dim W_DIP As Workbook
    Dim W_PD As Workbook
    Dim WDir As String
    Dim CTRL As String
    Dim PD_CTRL As Long
    Dim nRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim C As Long
    Dim PD_CELL As Range
    Dim firstaddress As String
    Dim LT_NUM As String
    Dim first_LT As String
    Dim ALL_LT As String

    '=============================
    ' Set Pointer to WorkSheets
    '=============================
    WDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    W_PD_DIR = WDir & ".\_database\POINT-DATA-ALL COLLECTOINS_v2.xlsx"

    Set W_DIP = ThisWorkbook

    Workbooks.Open (W_PD_DIR)

    Set W_PD = Workbooks("POINT-DATA-ALL COLLECTOINS_v2.xlsx")

    GDETrow = 17

    Do Until GDETrow = 41

        GDETrow = GDETrow + 1

        With W_PD.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")

            CTRL = W_DIP.Sheets("AFTER_SURVEY").Cells(GDETrow, 2)

            Set PD_CELL = Range("A:A").Find(What:=CTRL)

            If Not PD_CELL Is Nothing Then

                firstaddress = PD_CELL.Address

                Do

                    cRow = PD_CELL.Row
                    LT_NUM = W_PD.Sheets(1).Cells(cRow, 2)
                    Set PD_CELL = .FindNext(PD_CELL)
                    first_LT = LT_NUM
                    ALL_LT = first_LT & ", " & LT_NUM
                    W_DIP.Sheets("AFTER_SURVEY").Cells(GDETrow, 19) = ALL_LT

                Loop While Not PD_CELL Is Nothing And PD_CELL.Address <> firstaddress

            End If
        End With
    Loop

    W_PD.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: String concatenation in VBA can be done with the `&` (Ampersand) sign. Numbers are implicitly converted to strings if you do this. Otherwise you can use `CStr()`: `CStr(Var1) & ", " & CStr(Var2)`

Comment: If you want to concatenate them across different loops either build the string in the loop like this: `foo = foo & ", " & bar` or read the cell value, attach the new text and write it back like this: `someCell.Value2 = someCell.Value2 & ", " & anotherValue`

Comment: Also the name of this operation is concatenate/concatenation, not concentrate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `W_DIP.Sheets("AFTER_SURVEY").Cells(GDETrow, 19) = ALL_LT` is the line where the text is written, you can to this:

```vb
Dim rangeToChange as Excel.Range
Set rangeToChange = W_DIP.Sheets("AFTER_SURVEY").Cells(GDETrow, 19)

If IsEmpty(rangeToChange.Value2) Then
    rangeToChange.Value2 = ALL_LT
Else 'already text in the Cell, add value with comma
    rangeToChange.Value2 = rangeToChange.Value2 & ", " & ALL_LT
End If
```

Just replace the Line above with the Code provided.

This will fill the Cell with the value provided and only add the comma if there already is value inside the Cell.

.Value2 is used to avoid an implicit call to the default property of the cell.

Comment: It works great but not exactly how i wanted it to. It returns all the strings in the list e.g. 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 i only want to see [16, 5] in the cell. is this possible?

Comment: This would be a bit more involved, you could use a dictionary and always check if `.KeyExists` before adding the value. I'll update the answer as soon as I have some spare time.